# Как передать список в параметр с внутренним списком?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Доброе утро.

**Суть:** В различных библиотеках есть ряд параметров, вроде `ax=axes[1,2]` для `matplotlib`, которые содержат внутренний список.

**Вопрос:** Как передать список чисел внутрь подобных параметров? То есть, можно ли синтаксимом Python передать не список, а значения списка через запятую?

Просто передача списка:

```
test_list = [1,2]
ax=axes[test_list]
```

Не работает, ибо получается `ax=axes[[1,2]]`. Буду благодарен за любой совет :)

Comment: Какой тип у переменной `axes` - `type(axes)`? И какой тип ее элементов - `type(axes[0])`?

Comment: @MaxU <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: OK, а размерность? `print(axes.shape)`?

Comment: @MaxU У элементов <class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>

Comment: Всем будет проще если вы приведете в вопросе часть кода, где вы создаете `axes`...

Comment: @MaxU Размерность я указываю самостоятельно при генерации графика. Суть тут скорее не в особенности этой библиотеки, а возможно ли синтаксисом Python передать не список, а только значения списка через запятую, вроде *test_list и т.п.

Comment: все (почти) возможно! Это вопрос об индексации в Numpy arrays - чтобы дать корректный ответ надо знать размерность массива и то что вы хотите получить - например единичный элемент из 2D матрицы или вектор из 3D массива и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @MaxU Есть еще 5 или 6 библиотек, на моей памяти, которые принимают параметры в подобном формате, потому даже если найти решение, которое будет завязано на размерности и т.п., и в ручном порядке подойдет в данной задаче, далее оно будет неприменимо :) Если силами синтаксиса Python это реализовать нельзя, буду искать другие варианты. А вам большое спасибо за участие :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обращение к объекту через квадратные скобки неявно вызывает метод `__getitem__` объекта. Можно пойти от обратного, и вызвать этот метод явно. Но для начала лучше посмотреть что именно передается в этот метод.

Пусть есть простой класс:

```
class Test:
     def __getitem__(self, key):
         return key

t = Test()

print(t[1,2])  # Выводит (1, 2)
```

Т.е. по идее нужно просто передать в `__getitem__` кортеж с нужными параметрами:

```
print(t.__getitem__((1,2)))  # Выведет (1, 2)
```

С другой стороны, то же самое мы получим, если просто передадим кортеж в квадратных скобках:

```
print(t[(1,2)])  # Выведет (1, 2)
```

Т.е. с точки зрения Python вызовы `t[1,2]` и `t[(1,2)]` эквивалентны.

Для вашего случая можно просто перед индексированием привести список к типу кортеж:

```
test_list = [1,2]
ax=axes[tuple(test_list)]
```

Если вдруг понадобится передать список с сечениями (актуально для Numpy):

```
t[1:2, 3:4]
```

Строка вида `args = [1:2, 3:4]` вызовет ошибку синтаксиса.

Пробуем на нашем тестовом объекте:

```
>>> print(t[1:2, 3:4])
(slice(1, 2, None), slice(3, 4, None))
```

Видим, что в качестве сечений передается объект [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice). Таким образом, можно сформировать подобный кортеж с объектами `slice` внутри, передать в квадратных скобках, и это будет работать точно так же, как если бы сечения были заданы прямо в квадратных скобках:

```
>>> i = (slice(1, 2, None), slice(3, 4, None))

>>> print(t[i])
(slice(1, 2, None), slice(3, 4, None))
```

Вариант `i = (slice(1, 2), slice(3, 4))` тоже будет работать.